# Laravel 5.4 Toggle Between 2 Different ResetPasswordNotifications

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

How would you toggle between two different ResetPasswordNotifications?

I've got the usual reset password, but when a new user is created by an admin (in a separate controller) they also get a reset password "like" notification.  It would have different content, but same purpose by providing a URL with the generated and stored token appended.

The only way I can see how to do this is to:

1. Create my own PasswordBroker that inherits Laravel's PasswordBroker
2. Override PasswordBroker::sendResetLink to take an extra param
3. Register the new PasswordBroker in the PasswordResetServiceProvider
4. Then when it is invoked it takes the username param (original) and an extra param for toggling between notifications like

   Password::broker()->sendResetLink($username, $myNewToggleParam);

Is this the easiest way to do this and maintain the reset password functionality of creating and storing a token for a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution by taking a walk down to the `PasswordBroker`, and then into the `PasswordResetServiceProvider` to find out where it was instantiated in the service container, and then I was able to do this to send an alternative password reset notification to a user that was just created by an admin in the dashboard.

For brevity I only put in small amounts of the public endpoint, but added it for completeness in case the solution looses context without it:

```
/**
 * Store a newly created user in storage, and send a notification to
 * indicate the account was created and requires a password reset.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->authorize('store', User::class);

    $this->validate($request, [...]);

    $user = $this->create($request);

    $this->sendResetLinkEmail($user);

    return response()->json([
        'user' => $user,
        'message' => trans('user.created'),
    ]);
}

/**
 * Send a reset link to the new user.
 *
 * @param  User $user
 */
private function sendResetLinkEmail(User $user)
{
    // Reach into the service container for the password broker
    $passwordBroker = App::make('auth.password.broker');

    // Create a new token from the token repository, and send of the email
    // notification to the new user to reset their password
    $user->sendNewUserPasswordResetNotication(
        $passwordBroker->getRepository()->create($user)
    );
}
```

Don't forget to add the new notification to the User model.